# “Element could not be scrolled into view” when button is already visible

Tags: selenium-webdriver, firefoxdriver

I'm using Selenium 3.141.59 with a Firefox driver. I have a "flex" button very visible and very clickable (according to me) but selenium doesn't seem able to click on it.

Here is the button:

```
 <button id="modal" class="Button Button--primary" type="submit">Ok</button>
```

And the error message:

```
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: Element <button id="modal" class="Button Button--primary" type="submit"> could not be scrolled into view
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'TOTO', ip: '192.168.99.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_191'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, browserVersion: 65.0.1, javascriptEnabled: true, moz:accessibilityChecks: false, moz:geckodriverVersion: 0.23.0, moz:headless: false, moz:processID: 14000, moz:profile: C:\Users\Toto\AppData\Lo..., moz:shutdownTimeout: 60000, moz:useNonSpecCompliantPointerOrigin: false, moz:webdriverClick: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, platformVersion: 10.0, rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
Session ID: 5c303e2c-fa05-4ee5-a1f9-56607503baf3
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:285)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:84)
    at myRep.Stepdefs.iClickOn(Stepdefs.java:224)
    at ✽.I click on "modal"(C:/Users/Toto/IdeaProjects/MyProject/tests/UI_test/src/test/resources/myRep/require_data.feature:26)
```

Since just doing:

```
 WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id(id));
 element.click();
```

Wasn't working, I tried to add a wait but had no luck (the element never appear to be clickable):

```
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
 WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id(id));
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element));
 element.click();
```

However, I know the element is here and is visible since my program take screenshot when a test fail. Also, I did succesfully click on the button after my program ended (and I didn't needed to scroll for that...).

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49095333/10512595), I try to switch frame but it didn't worked either. I also tried using the `js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);` but still no luck.

So, Any idea?

---

PS: I'm also aware of [this question](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/32697/36046) but it didn't help me either.

---

### Additional notes:

- The button is in a "pop-in" who appear after a click on radio-button.
- I just notice that the DOM has a weird "shape" and I'm wondering if this could be the cause of the problem. Here is how the DOM looks like, you can notice that the footer is **before** the button:

  ```
  <html>
  <head>...</head>

  <body>
      <div id="app">
          <div>
              <header>...</header>
              <div>...</div>
              <footer>...</footer>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div>...</div>
      <div>
          <div>
              <div>...</div>
              <div>
                  <button id="modal" class="Button Button--primary" type="submit">
                      Ok
                  </button>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </body>

  </html>
  ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found the issue:

There was another, invisible element, with the same id. I believe that making the id unique will fix the issue.